# Continuous path of Fredholm operators

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a (infinite dimensional) Hilbert space and denote by $\mathcal{F}(H)$ the semigroup of bounded Fredholm operators in $H$. Let $S,T\in\mathcal{F}(H)$ and let $I=id_{H}$ be the identity map in $H$.
I know that $ST\oplus I$ and $S\oplus T$ are both elements of $\mathcal{F}(H\oplus H)$ and that they have the same index.

> **Question.** How can one explicitly construct a continuous map $\alpha\colon[0,1]\to\mathcal{F}(H\oplus H)$ such that $\alpha(0) = ST\oplus I$ and $\alpha(1)=S\oplus T$ ?

Writing $A\oplus B = \begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}$, I already notice that

$$\alpha(t) = \begin{bmatrix} ST & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi t/2) & -\sin(\pi t/2) \\ \sin(\pi t/2) & \cos(\pi t/2) \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & S^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi t/2) & \sin(\pi t/2) \\ -\sin(\pi t/2) & \cos(\pi t/2) \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & S \end{bmatrix}$$

seems to do the job, though I do not know how to check that $\alpha(t)\in\mathcal{F}(H\oplus H)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$. Besides, in the above formula I've assumed that $S$ is invertible, and I could not find a solution without that assumption.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map I was looking for is $\alpha\colon[0,1]\to\mathcal{F}(H\oplus H)$ given by
$$\alpha(t) =
\begin{bmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi t/2) & \sin(\pi t/2) \\ -\sin(\pi t/2) & \cos(\pi t/2)\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} T& 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi t/2) & -\sin(\pi t/2) \\ \sin(\pi t/2) & \cos(\pi t/2)\end{bmatrix}$$
since
$$\alpha(0) =
\begin{bmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} T & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} ST & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$\alpha(1) =
\begin{bmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I \\ -I & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} T & 0 \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -I \\ I & 0\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} S & 0 \\ 0 & T\end{bmatrix}$$

Also, $\alpha([0,1])\subseteq\mathcal{F}(H\oplus H)$ since $\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\pi t/2) \cdot I & \sin(\pi t/2)\cdot I \\ -\sin(\pi t/2)\cdot I & \cos(\pi t/2)\cdot I\end{bmatrix}$ is Fredholm in $H\oplus H$ and a composition of Fredholm operators remains Fredholm.